# Undefined reference error - object inside class

Tags: c++, class, object

Here is the problem:
Write three base class named Voltmeter, Ammeter and ResistanceMeter.
 Voltmeter class will have a member function volt, a non default constructor, a copy constructor
 and a function measureVolt().
  Ammeter class will have a member function amp, non default constructor, a copy constructor and
  a function measureCurrent().
  ResistanceMeter class will have a member function resistance, non default constructor,
  a copy constructor and a function measureResistance().
  Now write a class Multimeter which will
  have object of Voltmeter, Ammeter and ResistanceMeter so thus it can use the functionality of those class.

In my solution, the compiler say undefined reference on every object I used in the class 'multimeter'. Code is as below:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

class voltmeter{   //class - Voltmeter
    float volt;

public:

    voltmeter(); //default constructor
    voltmeter(float v){   //non default constructor
        volt = v;
    }

    voltmeter(voltmeter &ob) //copy constructor
    {
        volt = ob.volt;
    }

    void set_volt(float v)
    {
        volt = v;
    }
    float get_volt(void)
    {
        return volt;
    }
    void measure_volt(void) //measureVolt()
    {
        cout<<"Current volt in the circuit is: "<<volt<<"V"<<endl;
    }
};

class ameter
{
    float amp;
public:
    ameter();

    ameter(float a)
    {
        amp = a;
    }
    ameter(ameter &ob)
    {
        amp = ob.amp;
    }

    void measure_current(void)
    {
        cout<<"Current flow in circuit is: "<<amp<<"amp"<<endl;
    }

    void set_amp(float a)
    {
        amp = a;
    }
    float get_amp(void)
    {
        return amp;
    }

};

class res_meter //class - resistanceMeter
{
    float resistance;

public:
    res_meter();

    res_meter(float res)
    {
        resistance = res;
    }

    res_meter(res_meter &ob)
    {
        resistance = ob.resistance;
    }

    float get_resistance(void)
    {
        return resistance;
    }

    void set_resistance(float res)
    {
        resistance = res;
    }

    void meas_res(void)
    {
        cout<<"Current resistance in circuit is "<<resistance<<"ohm"<<endl;
    }

};

class multimeter
{
    res_meter r1;
    ameter a1;
    voltmeter v1;

public:
    multimeter(){
        r1.set_resistance(12.30);
        a1.set_amp(22.5);
        v1.set_volt(26.9);
    }
  //  ~multimeter();

    void show_info(void)
    {
        cout<<"Current Multimeter Status is as below: "<<endl;
        a1.measure_current();
        r1.meas_res();
        v1.measure_volt();
    }
};


int main()
{
    multimeter M;

    M.show_info();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declare a default constructor for all the classes (which is used in the `multimeter` class), but you never *define* the constructors.

Change e.g.:

```
class voltmeter
{
    // ...

    voltmeter();

    // ...
};
```

to

```
class voltmeter
{
    // ...

    voltmeter() {}

    // ...
};
```

Comment: +1; good spot; even more impressive if you didn't need to attempt compilation

Comment: On a more serious note, it would be a good idea to move the definitions of all the functions (including the constructors) to source files. That way your program will become more manageable as it scales.

Comment: thanks, I didn't know that could make a big difference. Actually, I'm learning from web and that's giving me pain now while working on exercises in lab.
can you please refer me a good book to learn cpp oop including this kind of things?

Answer (score 0):

> In my solution, the compiler say undefined reference on every object I used in the class 'multimeter'.

Read your warning messages more carefully. The compiler is telling you that the `multimeter` default constructor (which is defined) is referencing the default constructors for classes `ameter`, `res_meter`, and `voltmeter`'. It is those default constructors that aren't defined.

So define them, or use the non-default constructors that you did define.